# Dotnet test questions on errors

Tags: automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I am working on Azure pipelines, running on a Windows self-hosted agent, behind a firewall to run automated tests.
I would want to see the tests results and code coverage in the pipeline results in Azure.  My build pipelines are working but I never saw yet the results of automated tests so I'm not sure of what to expect.

I run this in my pipeline:

```
  - job: Test
    steps:
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: 'src/***.Test.Core/*.csproj'
          testRunTitle: '***Tests'
          arguments: '--collect "Code coverage"'
          publishTestResults: true
```

Here are extracts of the logs, with my questions and comments:

- Initialization of proxies and general stuff

> ```
> ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=http://***proxy.***.***:443
> ##[debug]Agent.ProxyBypassList=["***.***,localhost,127.0.0.1","***.***","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
> ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=*:\***Certificates\***PKIG2PEM.txt
> ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
> ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
> ##[debug]command=test
> ##[debug]projects=src/***.Test.Core/*.csproj
> ##[debug]arguments=--collect "Code coverage"
> ##[debug]publishWebProjects=true
> ##[debug]workingDirectory=*:\Agent\_work\24\s
> ##[debug]check path : *:\Agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.179.2\node_modules\packaging-common\module.json
> ##[debug]adding resource file: *:\Agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.179.2\node_modules\packaging-common\module.json
> ```

- Not sure what is CHCP but tests are run, with errors I believe linked to firewall so I'd expect to see those errors in the tests results

> ```
> [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
> ##[debug]publishTestResults=true
> ##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=*:\Agent\_work\_temp
> ##[debug]defaultRoot: '*:\Agent\_work\_temp'
> ##[debug]pattern: '**/*.trx'
> Results File: E:\Agent\_work\_temp\***_***_2020-12-17_16_13_24.trx
> Attachments:
>   *:\Agent\_work\_temp\d992768e-f36f-4558-9b52-f42fc7cd3c74\***_***_2020-12-17.16_13_16.coverage
> Failed!  - Failed:    29, Passed:     0, Skipped:     0, Total:    29, Duration: 3 s - OECD.Glue.Contacts.API.Test.Core.dll (netcoreapp3.1)
> ```

- Errors when pushing the results, what means "Failed to get FF TestManagement.Server.UsePublishTestResultsLibInAgent Value." ?

> ```
> ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
> ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
> ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[debug]BuildConfiguration=undefined
> ##[debug]BuildPlatform=undefined
> ##[debug]testRunTitle=***Tests
> ##[debug]adjustedPattern: '*:\Agent\_work\_temp\**/*.trx'
> ##[debug]Failed to get FF TestManagement.Server.UsePublishTestResultsLibInAgent Value.
> Unable to get the FF: TestManagement.Server.EnablePublishToTcmServiceDirectlyFromTask. Reason: One or more errors occurred. (Moved Temporarily)
> ```

- Failed to get FF TestManagement.PTR.CalculateTestRunSummary, what is CalculateTestRunSummary ?

> ```
> ##[debug]Failed to get FF TestManagement.PTR.CalculateTestRunSummary Value.
> ##[debug]Reading test results from file '*:\Agent\_work\_temp\***_***_2020-12-17_16_13_24.trx'
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[results.publish type=VSTest;mergeResults=false;runTitle=GlueContactsTests;publishRunAttachments=true;resultFiles=*:\Agent\_work\_temp\*_***_2020-12-17_16_13_24.trx;testRunSystem=VSTS - dotnet;]
> ```

- I wonder what to do with these warnings, I don't know much about Dotnet core and Nuget, my job is only the pipeline, not the underlying project.  In project settings, I see .Net Core 3.1, I don't understand where to look to find if I use Nuget version < 5.7 and if this warning applies to me

> ```
> ##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build 
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build 
> ##[debug]task result: Failed
> ```

- Then I have this, publish test results ends with Moved Temporarily, I'm guessing this is because of firewall, still, I did setup the proxy and other calls to Azure seems to work, what could be the issue ?

> ```
> ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : *:\Agent\_work\24\s\src\***.Test.Core\***.Test.Core.csproj
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : E:\Agent\_work\24\s\src\***.Test.Core\***.Test.Core.csproj
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : E:\Agent\_work\24\s\src\***.Core\***.Test.Core.csproj
> ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
> ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: Moved Temporarily
> ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
> ##[section]Finishing: DotNetCoreCLI
> ```

Thanks for any help, Claude

Update 1 ---------------------------------

Thank you.
I understood that my version of DotNet Core on the agent is not good,
the agent has version 5 while the project references version 3.1.

I added this task :

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.x'
```

But I am behind a firewall, still I have these logs:

```
##[debug]agent.proxyurl=http://***proxy.***.***:443
##[debug]agent.proxyusername=undefined
##[debug]agent.proxypassword=undefined
##[debug]agent.proxybypasslist=["***.***,localhost,127.0.0.1","***.***","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
##[debug]agent.proxybypasslist=["***.***,localhost,127.0.0.1","***.***","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_c11775e3-cd05-4e03-abd2-35da98ef2f0f_build_164_0
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 3.1.x.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Failed to download or parse releases-index.json with error: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"}
```

Would it be best to install this version locally ?  In that case, would I have to do something special so it uses the correct version ?

Update 2 ---------------------------------

Thanks for that link to a known issue.  I noticed that issue doesn't mention an error I have: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"}

Can it be that the task tries to reach 'https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/3.1/releases.json' but can't as we are behind a firewall ??

I don't understand why it tries to install DotNet Core as it is already installed but I don't know much about DotNet Core, I am only trying to run automated tests.

My last test included:

```
  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
    displayName: 'Authenticate with NuGet'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.101'
      installationPath: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: 'src/myProject.Test.Core/*.csproj'
      testRunTitle: 'myProject'
      arguments: '--collect "Code coverage"'
      publishTestResults: true
```

Logs contains:

```
##[debug]agent.proxyurl=http://proxy.myCie.com:443
##[debug]agent.proxyusername=undefined
##[debug]agent.proxypassword=undefined
##[debug]agent.proxybypasslist=["myCie.com,localhost,127.0.0.1","myCie.com","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
##[debug]agent.proxybypasslist=["myCie.com,localhost,127.0.0.1","myCie.com","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_xxx_build_173_0
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 3.1.101.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Failed to download or parse releases-index.json with error: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"}
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to download or parse releases-index.json with error: {"code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY"}
##[section]Finishing: UseDotNet
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, About the warning message, we could add task UseDotNet to specify the version, the error message is publish test result to summary page, this should be related to the version of the agent, could you try it with hosted agent and then share the result here?

Comment: Thank you, please see my Update 1

Comment: After some digging, I got more confused as several versions are installed on the agent, I wrote a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427754/what-net-core-version-to-use-on-agent  Thanks, have a great end of year celebration !!!   :)

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I'll be away from the pc until next year...  

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: I did a new test, still fails, I explain in Update 2. Thanks

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Hello, I still have issues with my automated tests, I explained my latest try in Update 2, always blocked by this message : "UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY" can it be linked to proxies ?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is similar to GitHub issue [#10969](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10969). It has something to do with internal GitHub repo/url. This is because the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) which we specify in the task is searched in releases-index file, which is accessible to public as well:

[image]

You could also check the [releases-index.json](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases-index.json#L14)

```
{
            "channel-version": "3.1",
            "latest-release": "3.1.10",
            "latest-release-date": "2020-11-10",
            "security": false,
            "latest-runtime": "3.1.10",
            "latest-sdk": "3.1.404",
            "product": ".NET Core",
            "support-phase": "lts",
            "eol-date": "2022-12-03",
            "releases.json": "https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/3.1/releases.json"
        },
```

In this case, I would recommend you to reopen the Issue [#10969](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10969).

Comment: I did a new test, still fails, I explain in Update 2.  Thanks.